# How can I open a file content placed in a listView?

Tags: java, android, file, listview, inputstream

So, I manage to list all the files that I saved from and edit text into a `listview` and it works fine. What I want now is to open them into an edit text field. There is my code down below. How can I do that ? I hope you'll help me.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.ListActivity;

public class Tab1 extends Activity
{

    private ToggleButton toggleButton1;
    private ImageView imageViewOn;
    private TextView textReceive;
    private Button refresh;
    EditText txtData;
    int data_block =100;
    private long lastTime = 0;

    private List<String> myList;
    private File file;
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            String data = msg.getData().getString("receivedData");
            // Affichage de data
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(t-lastTime > 100)
            {

                textReceive.append("\n");
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            textReceive.append(data);
        }
    };
       final Handler handlerStatus = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            int co = msg.arg1;
            if(co == 1) {
            } else if(co == 2) {
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);
       ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File(directory + "/Notes");
        final File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());

        }
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


            }
        }); 
            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Study `View.setTag(string)` method in android documentation. Then in your adapter class use `view.setTag(param)` ... Replace the view by the view name which you are returning and Param by file path ... 
Next, in `onItemClick` method call `view.getTag()`. This will return the file path. Open the file then using its path. I hope you got the point.

Comment: `setTag()` attaches a tag or meta data with each view of listview. This tag or meta does not appear to user. You are showing files names in view so use file path as tag to each view. The `getTag()` will return the file path.

Comment: thank you , it works .. but i did it with  String file_name = myList.get(position);
                File uri = new File(file, file_name); ///